# Equivalent method to arcpy.Raster(), but for a TIN

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, tin

I am creating a Python script in a toolbox in ArcGIS 10.0. When the input dataset is a raster, I can use:

```
myRaster = arcpy.Raster('elevation')
```

What should I do when the input dataset is a TIN? Is there an equivalent for TIN datasets?

I only have found "CreateTin_3d", but I dont want to create another TIN.

Comment: My understanding is that [arcpy.Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000051000000) defines the raster as an object rather than a dataset and that things like Feature Class (points) and TINs don't require this type of declaration because they are automatically an object. I've never run into a problem with just myTIN = "elevation_TIN". Are you encountering a specific error?

Comment: What function/procedure are you undertaking? When running a tool just supply the full path, or if the workspace is set to where the tin is then just the name. Same as for feature classes. Rasters are special, but only since arcpy.sa. before that they weren't; scripts prior to v10 use full path to raster rather than a raster object for input/output, so don't use the arcpy.Raster object as an example of loading a dataset... look more closely at functions like Clip or Append on how to treat non-raster datasets.